# Xamarin UI test alternative

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I started using Xamarin.UITest for cross-platform testing (IOS & Android).

With Android it worked instantly without any problem and it keeps forking even after any SDK update or JDK.. name it!

But for iOS there was so many issue encountered with the device agent that didn't want to start, the wrong Xcode commande one, the wrong Xcode. Some time it worked, but out of no where it crashes.. then you must clean, rebuild, retry, cross your fingers it doesn't crash or at least that it will launch..

But now April 19 2019, I had an iOS update, combine with an Xcode update and sadly, it doesn't work anymore. I made a lot of research and attempt to recover my test case:

1. Downgrade Xcode to 10.1
2. Downgrade Xcode commande line tool to 10.1
3. downgraded the OS!

To finally rethink it. It's not a good solid testing tool if it breaks at every updates.

On the AppCenter it still works for both platform. But to create your test, you have to run them locally.. You can't anymore with iOS and if you find how to make it work, let me tell you : **"See you for the next update!"**

**So the question is:**
What are the alternative to do some automated UI test for iOS & Android using Xamarin?

Comment: Hi, do you find a alternative solution, or you can show which error info in current project.

Comment: I don't have any experience in this, but you could probably use visual studio for mac, since Xamarin is supported by visual studio. Have a look [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/visual-ui-tests-ios-simulator-using-xamarin-appium/)

Answer (score 2):

### Xamarin.UITest Xcode 10.2 support

Sorry to hear about your difficulty with the Xcode update.

Unfortunately Xcode minor updates for the last several releases have tended to break local iOS simulator testing, and occasionally device testing. I've seen this be an issue since at least as early as Xcode 9.x versions.

For context, Xcode 10.2 support was added in this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.7.2002-dev

If you or future readers of this discussion still do end up using Xamarin.UITest, I recommend checking the release notes when new minor versions of Xcode come out to see if that support has been confirmed. Typically the support has been added in the 1st Xamarin.UITest package released after a new minor version of Xcode has been released.

(I generally haven't seen this issue with patch versions though, for example Xcode 10.2.1 didn't seem to cause any issues when it came out if it was run against a test suite that was working for Xcode 10.2)

### Other testing frameworks

As for other testing frameworks, if you're using App Center itself; then Appium (JUnit) or Calabash are both able to be used with App Center Test and can be used cross-platform to run against your IPA/APK, generally regardless of what was used to write the apps in the first place, like Xamarin.UITest. (Though each framework has slightly different set up requirements and limitations.)

Outside of App Center Test, there may be other testing frameworks you can use; but that gets more into individual developer opinion which strictly speaking is out-of-scope for Stack Overflow answers.

Answer (score 0):

Appium Studio which holds all the pros of native Appium. It also supports parallel execution with built-in test reporting mechanism. They also provide cloud devices with which you can check whether it is feasible for your project. Check out [their](https://docs.experitest.com/) documentation for more features.